# Namespace not declared at XML Node Transformation

Tags: java, xml, dom, bpmn

I  am trying to process a bpmn file into an own flow model. Actually, my problem does not relate at all to bpmn standard so consider this as a context issue.
I want to get an xml node and transform it to String in order to save later to a database.
What i am trying to do in the following code is to get the BPMNDiagram node, using xpath, and export it to as string but, when i try to export i get an expception about not declaring nsi namespace.
I have declared all the namespaces at xpath previous "query" but once i get this node and try to transform it, i get the error described below.
The xpath part is working properly since i am getting the right node. The problem appears at transformation phase.

XML File (partial)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI"     xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn" id="Definitions_1" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="1.2.1">
<bpmn:process id="PP-ProcessProva01" name="ProcesProva" isExecutable="true">
...
</bpmn:process>
<bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
<bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="PP-ProcessProva01">
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="StartEvent_1cp968c_di" bpmnElement="PP_EV_ENTRADA">
    <dc:Bounds x="-39" y="143" width="36" height="36" />
    <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      <dc:Bounds x="70" y="161" width="90" height="20" />
    </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Task_0ogrwwq_di" bpmnElement="PP_AC_VALIDACION">
    <dc:Bounds x="241.17552742616033" y="120.96118143459915" width="100" height="80" />
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_1bc244v_di" bpmnElement="EV_TR_PP_EV_ENTRADA-PP_AC_VALIDACION">
    <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="-3" y="161" />
    <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="241" y="161" />
    <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      <dc:Bounds x="21.459854014598534" y="151" width="90" height="20" />
    </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
  </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
</bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
</bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</bpmn:definitions>
```

This is my code:

```
String res="";
File file2 = new File("c:\\temp\\prova.bpmn");

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(file2);

HashMap<String, String> prefMap = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                put("bpmn", "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL");
                put("bpmndi", "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI");
                put("di", "http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI");
                put("dc", "http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC");
                put("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
                put("camunda", "http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn");
            }};
SimpleNamespaceContext namespaces = new SimpleNamespaceContext(prefMap);

javax.xml.xpath.XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(namespaces);
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/definitions/BPMNDiagram");
Node nodeDi = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODE);



Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
t.transform(new DOMSource(nodeDi), new StreamResult(res));
```

Error message:

```
Namespace for prefix 'nsi' has not been declared
```

Do i have to declare in a similar way the namespaces at transformation level? Can anybody, please, help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks! I have just added the error message.

Comment: The stacktrace could be usefull. I'm guessing here, but it seems your base document is invalid, not your transformation in and of itself (the stack trace will tell us if the error you encounter is at the document parsing level, or the XPath evaluation level).

Comment: Note that XSLT and XPath need a namespace aware DocumentBuilderFactory so make sure you first use `setNamespaceAware(true)` on your DocumentBuilderFactory before creating DocumentBuilders and parsing XML documents with namespaces.

Comment: Hello Martin, please, can you answer my question instead of making a comment? Thank you to your suggestion i've been able to solve my problem but the merit it's entirely yours. I will mark as the right answer.

Comment: @drusilabs, you can add answer yourself if the answerer is absent. It will help other researchers.

Comment: @Suncatcher Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment made by Martin Honnen i could solve my issue:

"*Note that XSLT and XPath need a namespace aware DocumentBuilderFactory so make sure you first use setNamespaceAware(true) on your DocumentBuilderFactory before creating DocumentBuilders and parsing XML documents with namespaces*"